# Moving files with extension from source to destination

Tags: bash, mv, extension

Hello i am trying to move all files with `.hi` and `.o` extension  from a target folder `/src` to another folder `/Obj`

So far i have tried:

```
    srcpath=$(pwd)"/src"

    ghc src/Main.hs > Logs/output.txt 2> Logs/Err.txt //this builds the project and generates the binaries and .hi files

    mv  *.hi *.o  $srcpath/src/ Obj/     //i want to move all these files to Obj/ folder but where do i place the extension arguments?
```

How should the command be: `mv extensions source dest ?` or `mv source dest extensions`

I have tried:

```
srcpath=$(pwd)"/src"
objpath=$(pwd)"/Obj"

ghc src/Company.hs > Logs/output.txt 2> Logs/Err.txt

mv *.o *.hi  $srcpath  $objpath
```

And i get the following error:

```
    mv: cannot stat '*.o': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '*.hi': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move '/c/Users/[..]/src' to '/c/Users/[...]/Obj/src': Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your command `mv *.o *.hi  $srcpath  $objpath` you are moving every file with *.o or *.hi plus the folder src from the current `$(pwd)` folder to Obj

If you want to move every *.o and *.hi which are located in the folder `src`, then you could use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
srcpath=$(pwd)"/src"
objpath=$(pwd)"/Obj"

mv $srcpath/*.o $srcpath/*.hi  $objpath
```

Make sure your bash script is running in the correct folder, so the `$(pwd)` command works properly.

**Edit:**

If you want to move a collection of files or files with a certain extension, you could change the script to look like that (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/7311363):

```
#!/bin/bash

srcpath=$(pwd)"/src"
objpath=$(pwd)"/Obj"

##declare an array variable
declare -a arr=("*.o" "*.hi")

##loop trough the array to move
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    mv $srcpath/$i $objpath
done
```

Comment: So there is no way to issue a collection of extensions for a given source folder?You must add them manually? `extension0 $srcpath.....extensionN $srcpath` ?Is there no way to do `[extension0...extensionN] $srcpath `

Comment: I edited my answer, so you could move a collection of file names

Comment: Thank you very much but could you please explain **1.** the `@` stands for the index ? **2.** when you write `$srcpath/$i` and `i` is `1`  for example ,it selects all the files with the `*.hi` extension?

Comment: **1.** yes, @ is the index. **2.** yes, you could change the script to test and run `mv $srcpath/${arr[1]} $objpath` and then only the *.hi files would moved

Answer (score 2):

You seem to treat `*.o` and `*.hi` as some kind of filters used by `mv`. This is not how it works. The tool expects paths. Your shell can expand `*.o` and `*.hi` to all suitable local paths from the current directory; if it worked, `mv` would see paths, not patterns. Apparently you have no matching files so these patterns are not expanded and get to `mv` as they are, hence

> ```
> mv: cannot stat '*.o': No such file or directory
> ```

etc.

These syntax may work:

```
mv ./src/*.o ./src/*.hi ./obj/
```

Still it will (somewhat) fail if there are no matching files in `./src`. You can introduce variables as you did, but

- you probably don't need `$(pwd)`, `srcpath="./src"` should be enough;
- in general you should quote your variables (but not patterns), e.g.:

  ```
  mv "$srcpath"/*.o "$srcpath"/*.hi "$objpath"
  ```

If there are too many files, you will hit `argument list too long`.

---

This alternative solution using `find` should work with high number of files or no files at all:

```
find "$srcpath" -name "*.o" -o -name "*.hi" -exec mv {} "$objpath" \;
```

See `man 1 find` to learn how `-exec` works. Also note that thanks to the quotes, strings like `"*.o"` are not expanded by the shell here; `find` gets them literally and uses its intrinsic pattern matching procedure.

The solution will run a separate `mv` for every file. We can pass many arguments to `mv` thanks to `find … -exec … {} +` syntax, but since the syntax requires these arguments to be at the very end, we need `mv` to support `-t` (it's not required by POSIX, so your `mv` may or may not support it):

```
find "$srcpath" -name "*.o" -o -name "*.hi" -exec mv -t "$objpath" {} +
```